# Maximal $\lambda_n$ such that for every doubly stochastic matrix $A$, there exists a permutation matrix $P$ such that $A - \lambda_n P \ge 0$.

Tags: graph-theory, optimization

The following is exercise 63 of chapter III from *Modern graph theory* by *Béla Bollobás*.

> Let $\lambda_n \geqslant 0$ be the maximal real number such that for every $n \times n$ doubly stochastic matrix $A$, there is a permutation matrix $P$ for which all the entries of $A - \lambda_n P$ are non-negative. Show that $\lambda_n = 1/\lfloor(n + 1)^2/4\rfloor$.

This question appears in the chapter dealing with flows, connectivity, and matchings.

A doubly stochastic (DS) matrix is a matrix in which all the row sums and column sums are $1$. Furthermore, each entry is non-negative.
A permutation matrix is a DS matrix with all non-zero entries being equal to $1$.

**My attempt.**

By considering the DS matrix $A$ to consist of all entries $1/n$, we see that $\lambda_n \le 1/n$.
On the other hand, by an earlier exercise, we know that every DS matrix can be written as a convex combination of all permutation matrices. That is, there exists $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_{n!} \geqslant 0$ with $\sum \alpha_i = 1$ such that $$A = \sum_{i = 1}^{n!} \alpha_i P_i.$$
Since the sum of $\alpha_i$ is $1$, there must be some $i$ with $\alpha_i \geqslant 1/n!$ and thus, we may subtract $\frac{1}{n!}P_i$ from $A$ and keep all entries non-negative. Thus, we have shown that $$\frac{1}{n!} \le \lambda_n \le \frac{1}{n}.$$